# Create links inside a list

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a list looking like this

```
<li class="list">text1</li>
<li class="list">text2</li>
<li class="list">text3</li>
```

and want to make the text to links, with this result using JavaScript

```
<li class="list><a href="#text1">text1</a></li>
<li class="list><a href="#text1">text1</a></li>
<li class="list><a href="#text1">text1</a></li>
```

I already did this, but don't know how to do next?

```
var link1 = document.createElement("a");
link.href = "#text1"
```

Is it possible to make a loop or something similar, so that I don't have to write the same code for all three links?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? If you've already edited the HTML with the links, why do you need to do anything with JavaScript? Are you dynamically changing the links? Are you trying to create them dynamically in the first place? Any clarification would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, first you need to find all of the list class tags and loop through them.

```
var lists = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
for(var i=0; i<lists.length; i++) {
```

Next find the text of the current list element, store it in a variable and then clear the element's text.

```
var text = lists[i].textContent;
lists[i].textContent = "";
```

Third, create the `a` element and make the textContent of the a element the text of the current list and the href, the current text plus the `#` sign.

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "#"+text;
a.textContent = text;
```

And finally append the a to the current list element.

```
lists[i].appendChild(a);
```

```js
var lists = document.getElementsByClassName("list");
for(var i=0; i<lists.length; i++) {
  var text = lists[i].textContent;
  lists[i].textContent = "";
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = "#"+text;
  a.textContent = text;
  lists[i].appendChild(a);
}
```

```html
<li class="list">text1</li>
<li class="list">text2</li>
<li class="list">text3</li>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the list elements adding the anchor HTML as a text replacement:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.list'), function (el) {
  var txt = el.textContent;
  el.innerHTML = '<a href="#' + txt + '">' + txt + '</a>';
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/eje53ba9/6/)